# FlyOutAnchor buttons are disabled when they refer to multiple JS functions

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I created a static FlyOut control with multiple buttons. On click of those buttons different JS should fire. I created Commanddefinition for every JS function and made a refernce to them inside buttons controls. But, my buttons become disabled. If all of the buttons refer to the same commanddefinition/ js function, works fine. What am I missing? Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Here's my code:

```
<RibbonDiffXml>
    <CustomActions>
        <CustomAction Id="Add_Dynamic_Menu"
            Location="Mscrm.Form.new_test.MainTab.Workflow.Controls._children">
            <CommandUIDefinition>
                <FlyoutAnchor Id="Sample.new_test.form.FlyoutAnchor.Static" Sequence="10"
                    Command="Mscrm.Enabled"
                    Image16by16="/_imgs/placeholders/ribbon_placeholder_16.png"
                    Image32by32="/_imgs/ribbon/newrecord32.png" LabelText="Sample Flyout"
                    Alt="Sample Flyout" TemplateAlias="isv">
                    <Menu Id="Sample.new_test.form.Menu">
                        <MenuSection Id="Sample.new_test.form.MenuSection"
                            Title="Menu Section Title" Sequence="15">
                            <Controls Id="Sample.new_test.form.MenuSection.Controls">
                                <Button Id="Sample.new_test.form.Controls.Button.FirstButton"
                                    Command="Sample.FirstButtonComand" LabelText="First Button"
                                    ToolTipTitle="First Button"
                                    ToolTipDescription="The first button" TemplateAlias="isv"
                                    Sequence="20"/>
                                <Button Id="Sample.new_test.form.Controls.Button.SecondButton"
                                    Command="Sample.SecondButtonCommand" LabelText="Second Button"
                                    ToolTipTitle="Second Button"
                                    ToolTipDescription="The Second button" TemplateAlias="isv"
                                    Sequence="20"/>

                            </Controls>
                        </MenuSection>
                    </Menu>
                </FlyoutAnchor>
            </CommandUIDefinition>
        </CustomAction>
    </CustomActions>
    <Templates>
        <RibbonTemplates Id="Mscrm.Templates"/>
    </Templates>
    <CommandDefinitions>
        <CommandDefinition Id="Sample.FirstButtonCommand">
            <EnableRules>
                <EnableRule Id="Mscrm.Enabled"/>
            </EnableRules>
            <DisplayRules/>
            <Actions>
                <JavaScriptFunction FunctionName="testfirstbutton"
                    Library="$webresource:new_testfirstbutton"> </JavaScriptFunction>
            </Actions>
        </CommandDefinition>
        <CommandDefinition Id="Sample.SecondButtonCommand">
            <EnableRules/>
            <DisplayRules/>
            <Actions>
                <JavaScriptFunction FunctionName="testsecondbutton"
                    Library="$webresource:new_testsecondbutton"> </JavaScriptFunction>
            </Actions>
        </CommandDefinition>
    </CommandDefinitions>
    <RuleDefinitions>
        <TabDisplayRules/>
        <DisplayRules/>
        <EnableRules/>
    </RuleDefinitions>
    <LocLabels/>
</RibbonDiffXml>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing looks fine, so double check the webresource names and everything.

An approach to troubleshoot
1) Switch everything to the webresource/function that works 
2) Add the other function to the JavaScript webresource and see if it still works (if it fails, then it was the javascript function(s)).
3) Switch one of the FunctionName's to the second function while keeping the websresource all the same.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of minor things I noticed.  Both of your buttons have the same sequence number.  I would change firstbutton to 10.  Second, you do not have the Mscrm.Enabled rule on the seconnd buttons command def.

These ribbons love to be finicky.